# Pandas dataframe replace with regex doesn't work

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with many rows. I want to use pd.replace to replace values in entire columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
list = ['MD 15241', 'MD', 'TD', 'TD 15487']
a = pd.DataFrame(list)
b = a.copy()

b.replace(r'[A-Z]{2}', 'USA', inplace = True)
b
```

output

```
    0
0   MD 15241
1   MD
2   TD
3   TD 15487
```

I tried r'MD' or r'TD' , it works.

Comment: You might want to add the tag `Pandas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `regex=True` in the `replace` method:

```
b.replace(r'[A-Z]{2}', 'USA', inplace=True, regex=True)

b
#0
#0  USA 15241
#1  USA
#2  USA
#3  USA 15487
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def replace_string_inside_df(df):
    df.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', inplace=True, regex=True)
    return df

print(replace_string_inside_df(df))
```